# regular expression with hash character

Tags: c++, regex, qt, qregexp

I'm having trouble recognising a potential hash character.  I am using the following pattern that recognises files of the form: id-1321952010.xml.  Some of these files may contain a # before the id therefore: #id-1321952010.xml need be picked up also.

Presently for the initial case I have:

```
QRegExp rxLogFileFormat("\\b^[a-zA-Z]+\\-[0-9]{10,10}\\.[xml]{3,3}$\\b");
```

I've tried adding '#?' before the boundary but cannot get it to work correctly, can anyone assist.

Comment: Why do you have the `\b` in there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply adding `#?` before the boundary will not allow the regex to match #id-1321952010.xml, because it will search for the start of the sting (`^`) after you've declared that there may be a hash before it, which is a conflicting rule.

To allow for this, [move the start-of-string delimiter to the beginning of the regex, outside of the word bound](http://regexr.com?2v8tq):

```
^#?\\b[a-zA-Z]+\\-[0-9]{10,10}\\.[xml]{3,3}\\b$
```

(also moved the end-of-string delimiter outside of the word bound for good measure)

#### Also,

Based on @Mat's comment, if you're matching the start and end of a string, you probably don't need the word bounds at all, as they become redundant.

```
^#?[a-zA-Z]+\\-[0-9]{10,10}\\.[xml]{3,3}$
```